# Intellij cannot find Derby jars

Tags: intellij-idea

As I checked out this project from Git with Intellij it seemed not to be able to resolve where the Derby jars were for it couldn't import the class `org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl`. You can see the picture bellow in which the right side is the one at issue and the jars don't have the navigating triangles to open up the classes. So how should I resolve this problem?

[image: Derby problem]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add this jar to your classpath. You can it in two ways:

1. Add Derby dependency to your project from [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby/10.12.1.1).
2. Derby DB is already included in the Java Development Kit (typically `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/db/lib/derby.jar`). Open your **Project Structure** (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>) and add it as a library to your project: [image]

---

Now it is available under **External libraries** in the Project View (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>):

[image]